# Validation of linked booleans in model - Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application has two linked boolean fields in one of the data tables that mark categories into which the record may fall. That is, these two fields may be `true` or `false`, and I require one (and only one) of them to be `true` for the record to be valid. (In case anyone's wondering, there may be more categories in future, so a simple binary option with a single field won't work for long and I want to solve the root problem.)

The options for the values and their overall validity in my application are thus:

```
field a   |   0   |   1   |   0   |   1
field b   |   0   |   0   |   1   |   1
========================================
valid?    |   N   |   Y   |   Y   |   N
```

I've got the following validation in place in the model:

```
  validates :a, presence: true, unless: :b
  validates :b, presence: true, unless: :a
```

This catches some error cases by ensuring that at least one of the fields is `true`. However, this validation allows *both* fields also to be true, which I don't want.

Is there any way to enforce this final validation option in the model (the fourth column in the table up top)?

At present, I'm catching it in the controller while the record's being created as follows (forcing "both true" to "both false", which the model will catch and reject):

```
    if params[:word][:a] == "1" && params[:word][:b] == "1"
      params[:word][:a] = "0"
      params[:word][:b] = "0"
    end
```

but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to do it!

Comment: I am curious: why are you managing categories in this way? It seems very unusual.

Comment: I have lists of words to be compared against a source text, currently with two categories. I considered using a single field with multiple possible values, but I'm likely to need to allow some categories to be combined in the future (rather than being exclusive as now) and therefore need to have more than one value for each record. Having a separate field for each category allows maximum flexibility. Does that make sense @jvillian ?

Comment: It seems like there is a `m:m` relationship between your records and your `categories`. In which case I might have expected to see a join table instead of booleans. But, I realize that's not your question...

Comment: Hmm. Interesting thought, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a custom validator like so:

```rb
validate :a_xor_b

...

def a_xor_b
    errors.add(:a_xor_b, "only one must be true") unless a ^ b
end
```

Essentially you want the [`XOR`](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/e067fb6a84-ruby-xor-operator) operator.

**EDIT** (in response to @jvillian 's comment):

If you want to make sure there is only one true value in a number of boolean values I suggest something like the following using [`.inject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject):

```rb
xor_fields = %i[a b c ...]

def validate_xor
    result = xor_fields.inject(false) do |acc, curr|
        val = send(curr)
        return errors.add(:xor, 'Multiple true values') if acc && val
        acc ^ val # in this approach equivalent to acc || val
    end
    errors.add(:xor, 'No true value') unless result
end
```

Comment: What happens when the OP adds `c`, and `d`, and `e`, and `f`, and `...`?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks @alex-kucksdorf, and thanks for the pointer to ^. I'll have a play and see what I can come up with.

Comment: And, to answer @jvillian, if there's logic to how the fields can or can't combine then it should be as possible to write it in a custom validator as in any other method! I'll just have to try and make sure the validations aren't too complicated. :-)

Comment: Just to confirm, the suggestion by @alex-kucksdorf works perfectly. Thanks very much!